# SharePoint Alternate Access Mapping Problem

Tags: sharepoint

I have an Info-path task form in a custom SharePoint workflow that I have made.

The custom task form says to the user you have a task you need to complete here is a link to the document that you need to fill out in order to complete the task.

However the client's server has an alternative access mapping.

I pass the generated workflow URL to the task form of the document in the item-metadata.xml however this does not take into account the alternate access mapping and therefore the link is the wrong URL on the client's machine.

How do I manage to generate a URL on the server that takes into account the access mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the AAM page which URL is the workflow using, Default?

If so what about swapping around the AAM so the one you want to use is listed as Default?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Yes I was thinking the access mappings must be setup wrongly although I am not really wanting to make a change on how the access mappings are setup in case I might cause problems on the clients server (they have a strange network setup). I actually thought there must be something I am doing wrong when I am generating the URL because It is currently giving the server address rather than the mapped address in the URL.